AccessDeniedException when creating global organization policy on aws using terraform
I get access denied exception when trying to attach a s3 policy at the organization level. cant really find any relevant info online regarding this.
data "aws_iam_policy_document" "block_s3_insecure_http_access" {

    # dome9 requirement - disallow all insecure access
    statement {
      principals {
        type        = "AWS"
        identifiers = ["*"]
      }
      resources = [
        "arn:aws:s3:::*"
      ]
      effect = "Deny"
      actions = [
        "s3:*"
      ]
      condition {
        test = "Bool"
        variable = "aws:SecureTransport"
        values = [
          "false"
        ]
      }
    }
}

resource "aws_organizations_policy" "block_s3_insecure_http_access" {
  name    = "block s3 insecure http access"
  content = data.aws_iam_policy_document.block_s3_insecure_http_access.json
}

resource "aws_organizations_policy_attachment" "block_s3_insecure_http_access" {
  policy_id = aws_organizations_policy.block_s3_insecure_http_access.id
  target_id = data.aws_caller_identity.current.account_id
}

aws_organizations_policy.block_s3_insecure_http_access: Creating...
╷
│ Error: error creating Organizations Policy (block s3 insecure http access): AccessDeniedException: You don't have permissions to access this resource.
│ 
│   with aws_organizations_policy.block_s3_insecure_http_access,
│   on organization.tf line 26, in resource "aws_organizations_policy" "block_s3_insecure_http_access":
│   26: resource "aws_organizations_policy" "block_s3_insecure_http_access" {
│ 
╵
Releasing state lock. This may take a few moments...

Exited with code exit status 1


You can add aws organization SCPs with AWS organisation IAM user or role, not with any of linked account credentials. Please check whether you are using AWS Organization management accounts' IAM role/user to do this task. Ref: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/organizations/latest/userguide/orgs_delegate_policies.html

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
